# Create custom form in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, custom, forms

i would like to have a custom form which is open as a pop up on click of button. The details entered in this form should be save in database and visible in admin panel. How can i do this? Is there any free module?

Comment: The custom form you want, will be for front end or admin panel?

Comment: For frontend.........

Comment: https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-open-a-popup-in-magento-2-when-a-user-clicks-a-button/

you can refer this and where content goes paste your form.